# Dragunov after recent patch

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I saw in the release notes for the most recent Xbox 360 that the Dragunov's recoil has been reduced. I've been using both it and the RSASS a lot with the suppressor attachment and kick proficiency. What is the new recoil comparison between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MW3 in-depth video explaining the Dragunov's buff: